# FullCalendar dayClick not working (does nothing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am trying to get the 'dayClick' function to work on FullCalendar, but when I press on any empty day, nothing happens. I have searched all over SO and cannot find any solutions or figure out what's going on.

Here is my code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'title',
                center: '',
                right: 'prev,next today'
            },
            defaultView: 'month',
            weekends: false,
            editable: false,
            selectable: true,
            events: "/Home/GetEvents/",

            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                alert('You clicked on event id: ' + calEvent.id
                    + "\nSpecial ID: " + calEvent.someKey
                    + "\nAnd the title is: " + calEvent.title);

            },

            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                alert("Day Clicked");
                $('#eventDate').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
                ShowEventPopup(date);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending further time on this and having confirmation from Ram Singh that his calendar worked fine with my code, I dug deeper into the packages I used and noticed I wasn't using bootstrap.js as this previously conflicted with my calendar. Consequently, I added this back in BUT updated it to the latest version in hope that it would resolve any dependency conflicts. I also updated all of my other packages to their latest versions in hope that this would also help and now it works perfectly! :)

Hopefully this information may help someone else!

Answer (score 28):

**Only relevant for FullCalender v2:**

I found that on my calendar the `div` with the class `fc-bg` was hidden by using `display:none;`. It turns out that this is what the `dayClick` event is attached to, and since it was hidden, I could not click on it.

The reason why the `fc-bg` class had been hidden was because of a print CSS that I included on the page. It turns out that it is super important that this stylesheet has `media="print"` on the link, otherwise it will always be used.

When including the FullCalendar CSS files on your page, ensure that the links are like this:

```
<link href="/css/vendor/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/css/vendor/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Didn't fix it for me. (Fullcalendar 3.0.0)

Comment: You are a god send, this was exactly my issue.

Comment: You made my day. Thanks you.

Comment: Perfect solution.

Answer (score 9):

I used fullcalendar in company project ,when the table in below window view ,The dayClick not working, finally I find  the css of "html{overflow-x:hidden}" result,I remove the css,it's ok.

Comment: apparently it's height: 100% on html that is causing it. That's kinda unfun because I need that one for my bottom footer.

Comment: Man, this was a hard one to debug. Using an external monitor with a lot of height, the bug never happend. Only on the move, with a smaller screen, the bug started happening, and also at random, because every time I had Chrome Dev Tools open at a different height (which made some rows of days clickable and some rows broken). Your solution works, I had to remove `overflow-x: hidden` from `html`. Thanks... a lot!

Comment: Declaring HTML as:
`<div id="calendar" style="overflow: auto;"></div>` worked for me

Comment: I'm using fullcalendar 4 beta and this solution is not working for me

Answer (score 7):

I think this will be useful if someone is using fullcalendar 4.2.0.

1. make sure interaction plugin is getting load.
2. instead of dayClick use dateClick. They have changed the event name.

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same issue when using v4.2.0.  Turns out that the interaction plugin wasn't loaded.  The event is also now called `dateClick` instead of `dayClick`.

A working example is below.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        height: 600,
        plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'interaction' ],  // interaction plugin must be specified
        
        dateClick: function(info) {
            alert('Clicked on: ' + info.dateStr);
            alert('Current view: ' + info.view.type);

            // change the day's background color just for fun
            info.dayEl.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        },
    });

    calendar.render();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.2.0/main.js"></script>

<!-- interaction plugin must be included after core -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/interaction@4.2.0/main.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: How to change the month view from month to day on dateclick?

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded the code and just added your dayClick code in demo code it is working fine. Please see the below code:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2016-01-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2016-01-07',
                end: '2016-01-10'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2016-01-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2016-01-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2016-01-11',
                end: '2016-01-13'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2016-01-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2016-01-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2016-01-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2016-01-12T14:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Happy Hour',
                start: '2016-01-12T17:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Dinner',
                start: '2016-01-12T20:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2016-01-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2016-01-28'
            }
        ],

            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                alert("Day Clicked");
            },
            eventClick: function (event) {
                alert('event');
            }
        });

    });
```

```
 <div id='calendar'>
```

i think you are missing to declare anything or you are getting any other error. Please check your Firebug console.

Comment: This is why I am so confused, I believe it should work. I'm debugging in Chrome and there are no errors as far as I am aware when I've checked the developer tools. I thought someone else may have had this issue and fixed it. The eventClick works fine, just the dayClick does nothing. What plugins have you imported?

Comment: @JamesLloyd, i have downloaded the code from http://fullcalendar.io/download/ and added the dayclick and eventClick events to the example.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was close to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39342912/6364246

dayClick only worked when I clicked on the screen visible without scrolling.
I changed html css{overflow-y:scrolling} to {overflow-y:visible} and worked

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with the fullcalendar v4.0.0 beta...
I created a patch until it will fixed:

```
$('.fc-slats tr').on('click', function(e) {   
e.stopPropagation();
var time:any = $(this).attr('data-time');
var parentOffset:any = $(this).parent().offset(); 
var positionX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
var width:any = $(this).width();
var dayOfWeek = (positionX) * 7 / (width);
dayOfWeek = Math.floor(dayOfWeek) + 1;
dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek == 7 ? 0 : dayOfWeek;

var auxDays:any = (moment(context.state.currentDate).day() - dayOfWeek) * -1;

var date:any = moment(context.state.currentDate).add('days', auxDays);
var auxTime:any = time.split(':');
date.set({hour:auxTime[0] - 0,minute:auxTime[1]  - 0,second:0,millisecond:0})
date = date.toDate();
const elem = document.getElementById('modalFormSchedule');
const instance = Materialize.Modal.getInstance(elem as Element);
instance.open();
});


// Style
.fc-nonbusiness {
pointer-events: none !important;
}
```