# FullCalendar dayClick won't work at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I've been trying to get Full Calendar's dayClick event to work. It won't work, I've tried so many different things. I don't know what the problem is, I can get things like eventClick to work perfectly fine.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            selectable:{
                month:false,
                agenda: false
            },
            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

                alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

                alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

                alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

                // change the day's background color just for fun
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

            }
        });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the issue? The event is not being triggered or there is an issue within that function?

Comment: The event is not being triggered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FullCalendar dayClick not working (does nothing)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988815/fullcalendar-dayclick-not-working-does-nothing)

Comment: could be an issue with your css, please check that link