# dayClick not working full calender

Tags: jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I am trying to get some response from `dayClick` , but when I am clicking there, nothing happen. I am giving my code below.

```
    $('.full_calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next, today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek',
    },
    defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [{"title":"Email","start":"2018-03-21","className":"background_f05050","calender_type":0,"lifecycle_todo_id":31},{"title":"Personal Call","start":"2018-03-23","className":"background_5c9bec","calender_type":0,"lifecycle_todo_id":11},{"title":"Personal Call","start":"2018-03-23","className":"background_5c9bec","calender_type":0,"lifecycle_todo_id":17},{"title":"Personal Call","start":"2018-03-29","className":"background_f05050","calender_type":0,"lifecycle_todo_id":33},{"title":"Personal Call","start":"2018-05-03","className":"background_5c9bec","calender_type":0,"lifecycle_todo_id":12},{"title":"Personal Call","start":"2018-05-03","className":"background_5c9bec","calender_type":0,"lifecycle_todo_id":18},{"title":"Personal Call","start":"2018-05-06","className":"background_5c9bec","calender_type":0,"lifecycle_todo_id":30},{"title":"Email","start":"2018-05-08","className":"background_f05050","calender_type":0,"lifecycle_todo_id":32},{"title":"Personal Call","start":"2018-05-09","className":"background_f05050","calender_type":0,"lifecycle_todo_id":34},{"title":"Follow Up","start":"2018-03-13","className":"background_f05050","prospect_no":"381299717","note_id":2,"calender_type":1},{"title":"Follow Up","start":"2018-03-19","className":"background_f05050","prospect_no":"873529032","note_id":7,"calender_type":1},{"title":"Follow Up","start":"2018-03-24","className":"background_f05050","prospect_no":"873529032","note_id":8,"calender_type":1},{"title":"Follow Up","start":"2018-03-22","className":"background_f05050","prospect_no":"873529032","note_id":14,"calender_type":1}],
    selectable: true,
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
      var result = '';
      switch(calEvent.calender_type){
        case 0: {
          fetchlifecycletododata(calEvent.lifecycle_todo_id);
          break;
        };

        case 1: {
          fetchnotesdata(calEvent.note_id);
          break;
        };
      }

    },
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
      console.log('hi');
    },
  });
```

It is working in [jsfidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jso51pm6/1379/), but not in my Html. ??

Comment: Please add the code instead of a link.

Comment: sure.. wait a minute.

Comment: There is error in events:{!! $calender_data !!}, check http://jsfiddle.net/jso51pm6/1365/

Comment: {!! $calender_data !!} is getting json data from php..

Comment: i have put the array data insted of {!! $calender_data !!} now @KK

Comment: Working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jso51pm6/1375/

Comment: @KK yes i have edited your jsfiddle and its working over there , but not working on my html.. :(

Comment: Check the browser console for any error.

Comment: @KK it is not giving any error on console :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution of my problem with help of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988815/fullcalendar-dayclick-not-working-does-nothing/35990977). And also writing below.

before I included full calender css as below

```
<link href="/css/vendor/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/css/vendor/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I just add media="print" tag in

```
 <link href="/css/vendor/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And my problem is resolved.